# How do I create a unique table for each product?

Tags: product, css, html

I created a table of information for my products with html and css. The problem is now : I got the **same** table for all my products and I need always a unique version for each product. So what file do I need to edit?

Comment: Not enough information. Can you show us table with information you created? Also what kind of information should be unique?

Comment: where are the comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see. So for all right side options you need to create attributes in Catalog > Attributes (example - Attribute name Effet with values + 220%, +215%, etc) Then assign correct attributes for products (example this product would have attribute Effet set to +220%) and then call all atributes in your table (example print $_product[effet]; ?>) Just make sure that the attribute is marked as "used in frontend"